Using slam_toolbox and Nav2 I get the following error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past
Using slam_toolbox and Nav2 on ROS2 Humble I'm trying to navigate and map my Gazebo simulation environment. The launch files I use for slam_toolbox and Nav2 are online_async_launch.py and navigation_launch.py from nav2_bringup. When I set a Goal Pose using Rviz2 the robot starts moving but after a few seconds I get the following error:
[ERROR] [1725527385.341357984] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 256.836000 but the earliest data is at time 257.352000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]

which leads to the generation of an invalid path and later the termination of the goal and the robot stops.
Also the error is generated a few times, as the same target frame is looked up but the earliest available data keeps increasing.
If the transform_tolerance parameter of the global and local costmap are increased I get the error at a later time.
I already checked if the use_sim_time parameter is set to true everywhere.
Here's the console output upon setting a Goal Pose:
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1725528783.577740284] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location (1.19, -0.01) to (3.65, 4.10)
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528783.598962474] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1725528783.599035023] [controller_server]: No goal checker was specified in parameter 'current_goal_checker'. Server will use only plugin loaded general_goal_checker . This warning will appear once.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528784.649372599] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528785.699369157] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528786.699368238] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528787.749374620] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528788.749371872] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528789.226499790] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing costmap to 264 X 407 at 0.050000 m/pix
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528789.799383669] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528790.849380520] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528791.849369395] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528792.899363105] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528794.181239141] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 31.392000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528794.181277384] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528794.181307150] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528794.198143252] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528794.199357612] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-1] [ERROR] [1725528794.199562373] [controller_server]: Invalid path, Path is empty.
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1725528794.199613591] [controller_server]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528794.228096161] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528794.228993004] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-1] [ERROR] [1725528794.229113394] [controller_server]: Invalid path, Path is empty.
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1725528794.229180182] [controller_server]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[bt_navigator-5] [ERROR] [1725528794.268361510] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Failed to get result for compute_path_to_pose in node halt!
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528794.268508551] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528794.268893356] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1725528794.269562113] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528794.541990752] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 31.752000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528794.542033834] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528794.542073400] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Client requested to cancel the goal. Cancelling.
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528795.535370840] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 32.742000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528795.535434943] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528795.535487533] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528795.549790676] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528796.533371938] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 33.742000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528796.533406073] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528796.533458473] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1725528796.550201047] [behavior_server]: Running spin
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1725528796.550400498] [behavior_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin behavior.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1725528798.250594496] [behavior_server]: spin completed successfully
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528798.583312407] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 35.792000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528798.583368254] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528798.583415975] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528798.599776549] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528799.226482457] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing costmap to 315 X 407 at 0.050000 m/pix
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528799.533247301] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 36.742000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528799.533304721] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528799.533346080] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1725528799.550299045] [behavior_server]: Running wait
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1725528804.550529098] [behavior_server]: wait completed successfully
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528804.883002788] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 42.082000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528804.883064916] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528804.883117577] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528804.899904305] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528805.533824374] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 42.732000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528805.533913354] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528805.533978869] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1725528805.550189026] [behavior_server]: Running backup
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1725528811.650597043] [behavior_server]: backup completed successfully
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528811.983199544] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 49.172000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528811.983244861] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528811.983280619] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528811.999831116] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528812.533787201] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 49.722000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528812.533832748] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528812.533903834] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1725528812.549769112] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528812.550044608] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528813.533938295] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 50.722000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528813.533979324] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528813.534019130] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528813.549771192] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528814.533550553] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 51.712000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528814.533584708] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528814.533624725] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1725528814.550270404] [behavior_server]: Running spin
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1725528814.550390172] [behavior_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin behavior.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1725528816.250597519] [behavior_server]: spin completed successfully
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528816.583166189] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 53.762000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528816.583202208] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528816.583236884] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528816.599802029] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1725528817.533403060] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 30.805000 but the earliest data is at time 54.712000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528817.533446513] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1725528817.533508090] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[bt_navigator-5] [ERROR] [1725528817.559641434] [bt_navigator]: Goal failed
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1725528817.559699144] [bt_navigator]: [navigate_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1725528819.226500475] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing costmap to 321 X 407 at 0.050000 m/pix

Once the goal is aborted and I set another Goal Pose the robot again moves a bit and the whole thing starts again, so the termination of the navigation process seemingly "resets the problem".
Running ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames yields the following:

My best guess is that the problem is at least related to slam_toolbox as it provides some of the transformations. Where could the error be and how would I best troubleshoot it. I'd appreciate any and all input as I'm at my wits end!

Use message_filters package. It synchronizes the Timestamp from different topics.

To set a goal pose in Rviz2, make sure you've configured the fixed frame correctly. Here's how to do it:

In the Global Options panel, navigate to Fixed Frame.
Set the Fixed Frame to map.

This ensures that your goal pose will be referenced relative to the map frame. Otherwise, you might trigger unnecessary transform computations between different frames.
